# Unable to use GeoJSON using leaflet package in R

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to plot the GeoJSON in R using Leaflet package. Below is the code and the error.

```
  library(geojsonio)
    library(leaflet)
    library(data.table)
    library(plyr)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(rgeos) #for simplification
    library(leafletR)
    library(sf)
    library(jsonlite)
    library(RJSONIO)

    mydata <- fromJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/senthilthyagarajan/eb7a2771eab4639e94d5f9eaad28cb33/raw/1cfe355a56d2c1856a70a5389a4eadf06d782748/data.geojson",flatten=TRUE)


    leaflet(mydata) %>%
      addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", nghbrhd)(nghbrhd),
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                      bringToFront = TRUE))


    Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                           FeatureCollection
                         (right here) ------^
```

Please ignore the long list of packages mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to be of "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" type. When I run your code above, mydata is of type list which produces the error. I used geojson_read from geojsonio package to read the data (specifying the sp: spatialpolygons data type) and I get a leaflet plot. Flatten is not a parameter in geojson_read function but you can look into the parse argument to turn a geojson object in a dataframe if interested.

```
library(leaflet)
mydata <- geojsonio::geojson_read("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/senthilthyagarajan/eb7a2771eab4639e94d5f9eaad28cb33/raw/1cfe355a56d2c1856a70a5389a4eadf06d782748/data.geojson",what = "sp")

leaflet(mydata) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", nghbrhd)(nghbrhd),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ran the same code as yours and get this error now:
` Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!is.na(data[[n]])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used `

Comment: @SNT: one of the packages that you have previously loaded conflicts with the geojsonio package. Restart your R session and rerun the code I have above (I also added the leaflet library so you only have the leaflet and geojsonio libraries in your restarted environment minimizing conflict).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is their a way to debug such conflicts as in with breakpoints.

Comment: Typically conflicts arise when packages that perform similar tasks are both loaded in the environment. It helps to just restart the session and start anew with only the libraries of interest loaded in the environment.